# About a sequence in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Given that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a complete metric space $X$ satisfying $d(x_n, x_{n-1})\le 3^{-n}$. Prove the following:
(i) $(x_n)$ converges to some $x\in X$.
(ii) $d(x_n, x)\le \frac{1}{2}3^{-n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(x_{n+m,x_n})\leq d(x_{n+m},x_{n+m-1})+...+d(x_{n+1},x_n)
\leq {1\over 3^{n+m}}+...+{1\over 3^{n+1}}$

$\leq {1\over 3^{n+1}}{{1-{1\over 3}^m}\over {2\over 3}}\leq {1\over 2}{1\over 3^n}$ this implies that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence thus converges towards $x$.

$d(x_n,x_{n+m})\leq {1\over 2}{1\over 3^m}$ implies that $d(x_n,lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}x_{n+m})=d(x_n,x)\leq {1\over 2}{1\over 3^n}$.

Comment: Is there a typo in the last line? Is that $\frac{1}{3^m}$ should be $\frac{1}{3^n}$?